# Pandas short answer

Tags: python, pandas

I have been asked (using **pandas**) to answer the following question:

> How many married women over age 50 embarked in Cherbourg? Note:
>   'first' is a function in Pandas, so `'titanic.first'` will generate an
>   error; use `'titanic['first']` instead.

This is the data that is being used:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GhwOG6sH2JkNAxB664T7nmrob1aPYKlcVfKlTeXmzCw/edit?usp=sharing

I have come up with this so far, but keep getting syntax errors:

```
criteria = titanic['first']str.contains('Mrs.')&(titanic.age > 50)&(titanic.embarked.str.contains('Cher')]
number = criteria.last.count()
print number
```

Comment: smell like a homework :-)

Comment: You should probably just use the `gender` column, no?

Comment: `...irst']str...`?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple syntax errors here plus last is also a built-in function:

```
criteria = df.loc[(df['first'].str.startswith('Mrs.')) & (df['age'] > 50.0) & (df['embarked'] == 'Cherbourg')]

number = criteria['last'].count()
```